# Purpose of partitive

Tags: partitives

I'm having difficulty understanding the purpose of the partitive here.

> A crew of men were on board a ship.

According to CGEL (p. 349),

> The most straightforward type of quantification involves a quantifier in determiner or modifier function: *many books*, *these three houses*. But quantification can also be expressed by means of a noun as head with an *of* PP as complement. We are concerned in this section with the case where the quantificational noun is non-count, as in *a lot of people*.
>
> There are three versions of this non-count quantificational noun construction to be considered, as illustrated in [53], where double underlining marks the quantificational noun and single underlining marks what we shall call the oblique, the NP complement
> of *of*:
>
> [53] singular (a) and plural (b)
>
> ia. [A lot of work] was done.
>
> ib [A lot of errors] were made.
>
> iia. [A great deal of work] was done.
>
> iib [A great deal of errors] were/was made.
>
> iiia. ∗[Dozens of work] was/were done.
>
> iiib.[Dozens of errors] were made.
>
> In [i] the number of the whole NP depends on the oblique: we will say that *lot* is number-transparent in that it allows the number of the oblique to percolate up to determine the
> number of the whole NP. In [ii], singular *deal* selects a singular oblique, while in [iii] plural *dozens* selects a plural oblique. (We include both *was* and *were* in [iib] and [iiia] to show that the ungrammaticality is not a matter of subject–verb agreement but lies
> within the NP.)
>
> The obliques may be either partitive or non-partitive:
>
> [54] i [A lot of the delegates] complained. [partitive]
>
> [54] ii [A lot of people] complained. [non-partitive]
>
> In [i] the whole NP picks out a subset of the set referred to by the delegates, whereas there is no such subset relation involved in [ii]. The partitive obliques are normally definite and are distinguished from the non-partitives in that they occur in the fused-
> head construction:
>
> [55]i [Many of the delegates] complained. [partitive]
>
> [55] ii *[Many of delegates] complained. [non-partitive]
>
> Instead of [55ii] we have simply *[Many delegates]* complained, where there is no embedding of one NP within another.

As you can (hopefully) see, for an oblique to be considered 'partitive' it must be definite. Therefore, in the given sentence ("A crew of men were on board a ship"), the complement of *of* ('men') is not partitive, and as a result the entire NP ("A crew of men") does not pick out a subset of a set.

My question here, then, is this: what exactly is the semantic purpose of the partitive NP "A crew of men", if it does not have any subset relation (which is what, ere reading this particular section of CGEL, I had thought the sole purpose of partitives was: to pick out a subset of a set)?

Many thanks.

**Note: I originally thought it best to post this question on the English Learners StackExchange, but after receiving no answers there (likely because this question is not suitable for the Learners StackExchange), I have opted to re-post it here, in the hope of receiving more technical answers.**

Comment: I think it's explained thoroughly in CGEL.

Comment: I think that the purpose of the partitive oblique is explained very well; however, insofar as I can see, there is no real explanation of the semantic purpose of the nonpartitive oblique. Perhaps you could enlighten me.

Comment: You quote "The partitive obliques are normally definite" and later you say "to be considered 'partitive' it must be definite". *Normally* does not mean the same as *must*. (I'm not going to discuss the rest because it is hard to be certain what exactly is being discussed without the CGEL to hand.)

Comment: StuartF. You're right; however, I cannot think of any examples where the partitive oblique is indefinite, nor are there any examples of indefinite partitive obliques in CGEL (though I will have to double-check that).

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to reproduce long passages from a textbook and then ask people to explain what the authors meant, which probably explains why you didn't receive any responses over on ELL. Whatever, how can an indefinite number of people form a set? That would be a contradiction in terms. It's precisely because the people are not defined that they cannot form a set.

Comment: BillJ. I now understand what a nonpartitive oblique *doesn't* do: it *doesn't* pick out a subset of a set, and it is for this reason that it is indefinite. Before reading the CGEL section, my erroneous thinking was that all partitive obliques picked out a subset of a set; the idea of grammatical definiteness did not even come into my mind. For that reason, I was left - am still left - confused as to the purpose of the nonpartitive oblique. I know what it doesn't do, but not what it does, if you see what I'm saying.

Comment: It's purpose is to indicate that there were some people, though they didn't form a defined set. In other words, it means "A lot of people from some unspecified number of people ... ". "A lot of x complained; x = people".

Comment: As I've just had to explain to several people in comments, little words like _of, that, at,_ etc. don't have meanings so much as uses. If you want to have a special  name (e.g, "partitive oblique") for quantifiers with _of_, fine. But there's nothing special about them semantically; syntactically they're a mild variant, like _look at_ instead of _see_.

Comment: "A crew of men" is rarely regarded as involving a true partitive, though it does have the same 'a NP₁ of NP₂' surface structure. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive) has: 'A true partitive ... has the interpretation of a quantity being a part or subset of an entity or set' (say a half of the rice, 50% of the electorate). Other such structures are named in assorted ways; one term is 'pseudopartitive'.  'A box of chocolates' refers to box + contents. 'A shedload of money' is termed a fuzzy quantifier structure....

Comment: 'A crew of men' / 'a breadth of bacteria' are semantically-charged quantifier structures.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a partitive construction, since "crew" is not a quantificational noun. Compare:

1. The men were waiting. **A number of** them were angry.
2. The men were waiting. **A lot of** them were angry.
3. * The men were waiting. **A crew of** them were angry.

Note that (3) is incorrect. In fact, "crew" can never be used to pick out a subset of a definite group of items in this way.

"A crew of men" does not refer to some subset of "men" *per se*; instead, it means a crew *consisting* of men.

Comment: 'A score of', though involving a pseudo-numeral, is not considered to be a partitive either. Quantifiers (which many including myself see as different from numerals [partly as being  exact]) aren't restricted to stipulating indefinite subsets.